# Geometry Nodes Random Value doesn't output a Vector...?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am computing a random `Vector` value in geometry nodes. My issue is that I can not seem to connect this random vector output to a Scale `Vector` - or to the translation or rotation vectors for that matter.

Why can I not connect these two vectors together?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The node `Random` is funny in this respect.

On the one hand it can return a single constant random value, but on the other hand it can return a whole range of random values, depending on the case in which it is to be applied.

If you look closely, you can currently see diamond-shaped outputs on your node.

Simply put, these outputs give you as many randomly generated values as the number of points in your mesh.

However, the node `Transform` requires a single value, since it treats the points as a whole object and does not look at each point individually (`Set Position` would, however).

In this case you would just have to pass an integer value into the *ID* input of the `Random` node, and it will switch to a simple output (circle instead of diamond).

[image]