# Input for size of Cube node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to generate a cube of random size using Geometry nodes. What can I use to provide the random size as input to Cube node? Using "Random value" node with "Vector" data type shows me an invalid connection.

I'm using Blender 3.2.1

[image: invalid connection between random value and cube nodes]

Comment: Just plug an input node of type *Integer* with any value into the input *ID*.

Comment: For more details and screenshots have a look here [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/263182/107598) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/254664/107598)